# How to reset my npm's and plugins in Ionic2

Tags: npm, ionic2, ionic3

Is possible to re-install my project npm's and plugins ?

I want to remove unused ones and get the last version of npm's and plugins without rewrite the codes of my project

Comment: For `npm` modules, you can just remove the `node_modules` folder from the root of the project and then run `npm install`. But for the plugins, you need to be careful because the new version of some plugins can include some breaking changes and that will force you to update the code of your app.

Comment: @sebaferreras thank u very much.. I did 

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so we can close this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `npm` modules, you can just remove the `node_modules` folder from the root of the project and then run `npm install`.

But for the plugins, you need to be careful because the new version of some plugins can include some breaking changes and that will force you to update the code of your app.